# FFmpeg and DirectSound/XAudio2 in C#

Tags: c#, directx, ffmpeg, directsound, libavcodec

I have been attempting to get this working for a while and am a bit stuck.

I am attempting to be able to play a video in C# using libavcodec outputting to DirectX and either DirectSound or XAudio2. I have managed to get it to play a video, but am stuck on getting it to output sound.

It doesn't help that I have had no experience with either of DirectSound or XAudio2, or that libavcodec has little documentation. I have managed to get the audio codec, but am stuck trying to decode it or output it through DirectSound/XAudio2.

If anyone is able to either point me in the right direction, or just tell me how to do it I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently doing approximately the same thing as you and am also stuck at the same point! All I can tell you for now is, if you haven't found it, there's a good tutorial showing how to do it with SDL at [An ffmpeg and SDL Tutorial](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.html), using SDL_Audio for audio playback.

I am looking to see how to adapt this for XAudio2 or DirectSound and if I find anything more I'll let you know. Am currently reading through the official [XAudio2 documentation at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee415737%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Good luck!